# Validate form using Jquery with border and blur effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wish to validate a simple table form using jquery. So far I have a for loop that loops through all the fields and checks if they are empty. Then I have another for loop that checks to see if the age is within a certain range. And finally, the last loop checks to see if the email is in the correct RegEx pattern.

Currently only the first loop is working while the others are not being looped through. I have tried to do console.logs and it confirmed that the other loops are not being touched. Any ideas or help would be appreciated!

Semi working Code pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZXVmQz?editors=1010

Code:

**HTML**

```
<section class="container">
<div class="table table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered" id="data-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>Email</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="TextBoxContainer">
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="5">
        <button id="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Add more controls"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>&nbsp; Add&nbsp;</button></th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
function validate(input) {

    var isValid;
    var filter = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/;
    var email = $('.email').val();
    var length = $('.data').length;
    console.log($('.email').val());
    var rowInputLength = $("#TextBoxContainer input").length;

    for (var i=0; i<rowInputLength; i++) {

        if (!($(input[i]).val() == "" )) {

            isValid = true;
            validBorder($(input[i]));

            if ($('input[type=number]') && !($(input[i]).val()<= 2 || $(input[i]).val() >= 100)) {
                isValid = true;
                console.log($('#age').val());
                validBorder($(input[i]));
            }

            if ('$(input[i][type=email])' && filter.test(email)) {
                isValid = true;
                validBorder($(input[i]));
            }
        }
        else {
            isValid = false;
            invalidBorder($(input[i]));
        }
    }

    return isValid;
 }
```

**How the table is created**

```
function GetDynamicTextBox(value1, value2, value3) {

    return '<td><input name = "DynamicTextBox" id="name"  type="text" value = "" placeholder = "' + value1 + '" class="form-control data" /></td>' + 
           '<td><input name = "DynamicTextBox" id="age"  type="number"  min="3" max="100" value = "" placeholder = "' + value2 + '" class="form-control data" /></td>' + 
           '<td><input name = "DynamicTextBox" id="email"  type="email"  value = "" placeholder="' + value3 + '" class="form-control data email" /></td>' + 
           '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-success edit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></button></td>';
}
```

**When this button is pressed:**

```
$(function () {

    $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {

        var div = $("<tr />");
        div.html(GetDynamicTextBox("Enter Name", "Enter Age", "Enter Email"));
        $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
        $('#btnAdd').attr("disabled", "disabled");

        $(".data").blur(function() {
            validate($(this))
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You have duplicate ids for your inputs. id="age" or any other input have duplicates so your code will not work as you want it to

Comment: Also this `!($(input[i]).val() == "" )` can be simplfied to this `( $(input[i]).val() !== "" )`

Answer (score 0):

You lacked the relevant piece of code in the question, had to find it in your pen.

In your anonymous "Add Row" function you need to call validation with all of the input fields, using the selector you attempted to use can be done like so:

```
validate( $( ".data" ) )
```

Also other issues found in validate method: `$(input[i]).val()` is a string, convert it to a number using prefix +, `+$(input[i]).val()`